# Bash loop to read line by line and create folder by line index

Tags: bash

I am trying to do the following in a bash file:

```
mybash.sh myinputfile.txt myloopfile.csv
```

Create a **for loop**, that reads **myloopfile.csv** line by line, and then creates a folder which will take the line number as the folder name prefixed to "folder", ex. folder1, folder2...
and then inside this `folder$i` create a folder called **input** and another called **output**.
write the `line$i` content into a file called **myline.txt** and put this file inside the `folder$i/input`
and copy the file **myinputfile.txt** that i will pass as a parameter to the bash file inside the `folder$i/input` as well.

and then run my personal script that takes two arguments:

```
python myscript.py -i ./folder$i/input -o ./folder$i/output
```

and done!

**myfile.csv**

```
101,1001,10012,100121
102,101213,11122.1,12.15
103,122.15,155.2,1515.54
104,154.4,4551.1,454
```

what I currently have:

```
#!/bin/bash

while IFS='' read -r line || [[ -n "$line" ]]; do
    mkdir ./folder$line
    echo "$line"  >> Folder$line/input/myline.txt;
    cp myinputfile.txt Folder$line/input
    python myscript.py -i ./folder$i/input -o ./folder$i/output

done < "$1"
```

the problem is that I can't get the line index to pass it as a suffix to the folder name, so I currently get the line content.and I don't know how to read the two files from the arguments that i pass to the `mybash.sh`.

Comment: @chepner: that one is for you :)

Comment: minor nitpick: question and tag mentions for-loop, but code uses while loop (which is actually preferable in this case)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use a counter to keep track of line numbers:

```
#!/bin/bash
input_file=$1
csv_file=$2

count=1
while IFS= read -r line || [[ -n "$line" ]]; do
  input_dir="./folder$count/input"
  output_dir="./folder$count/output"
  mkdir -p "$input_dir" "$output_dir"
  printf '%s\n' "$line" > "$input_dir/myline.txt"
  cp "$input_file" "$input_dir"

  python myscript.py -i "$input_dir" -o "$output_dir"
  ((count++))
done < "$csv_file"
```

Comment: wooorking like a chaaarm